# How is ssh started during init?

Tags: server, ssh, init

How does the ssh daemon start on Ubuntu server? I see `/etc/init.d/ssh`, but I don't see any sym-links to it from the `rc?.d` directories.

I have a situation I'm trying to troubleshoot where a server becomes unresponsive on reboot after I add my own script to the shutdown/startup process with `update-rc.d client-services defaults 98 02`

On reboot, ssh shuts down, and that's the last I hear of the box (I don't have console or syslog access so I'm working blind here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it uses upstart, instead of System V init.  Take a look at /etc/init/ssh.conf.

Take a look at Anarci's post explaining Upstart from your other question:  [How to write an init script that will execute an existing start script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72123/how-to-write-an-init-script-that-will-execute-an-existing-start-script/72179#72179)

I don't know much about Upstart, but I do know that it is intended to replace System V init, and is used for many of the startup processes in Ubuntu now.